# How to add text only on my profile picture?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanna add the word "cover" on the current profile pic of my `FlatList`.

On my `FlatList` I have a few pictures, when I clicked and I change my current profile epic, I want just the word "cover".

I tried to add a condition, but it doesn't work properly.

```
  const { firstName, lastName, profilePictureURL } = currentUser;
  const userLastName = currentUser && lastName ? lastName : ' ';
  const userfirstName = currentUser && firstName ? firstName : ' ';


{myphotos.map((photos, i) => (
                    <View key={'photos' + i} style={styles.slide}>
                      <View style={styles.slideActivity}>
                        <FlatList
                          horizontal={false}
                          numColumns={2}
                          data={photos}
                          scrollEnabled={true}
                          renderItem={
                            (({ item, index }) =>
                              item.add ? (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                  key={'item' + index}
                                  style={[
                                    styles.myphotosItemView,
                                    {
                                      borderWidth: 1,
                                      borderColor: '#5DD6FF',
                                    },
                                  ]}
                                  onPress={onSelectAddPhoto}>
                                  <Icon
                                    style={styles.icon}
                                    name="add"
                                    size={40}
                                    color="#5DD6FF"
                                  />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                              ) : (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                  key={'item' + index}
                                  style={styles.myphotosItemView}
                                  onPress={() =>
                                    onSelectDelPhoto(i * 6 + index)
                                  }>
                                  <FastImage
                                    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                                    source={{ uri: item }}
                                  />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                              ),
                            photos  ===
                              profilePictureURL(<Text>Couverture</Text>))
                          }
                        />
```

Comment: are u trying to add water mark on pic or simply want to add text on picture while displaying..

Comment: yes water mark !

Comment: please specify the problem. did you want to add text when there is no Image like you want to display first character of first and last name or you want to ad txt on image. just like a watermark.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                  key={'item' + index}
                                  style={styles.myphotosItemView}
                                  onPress={() =>
                                    onSelectDelPhoto(i * 6 + index)
                                  }>
                                  <FastImage
                                    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                                    source={{ uri: item }}
                                  />
                                  <Text
                                  style={styles.watermark}
                                  >STARK</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                


const styles=StyleSheet.create(
{
    watermark:
    {
        alignself:"center",
        position:"absolute"
    }

    myphotosItemView:
    {
        justifycontent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    }
})
```